# __init__(self) -> None: vs __init__(self): in python

Tags: python

What is the difference between 1) `__init__(self) -> None:` and 2) `__init__(self):` ?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 5

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5

print (" A : ", A().a)
print (" B : ", B().a)
```

Comment: At runtime, nothing. Type hints are only used by external tools.

Comment: The `-> None` syntax is an example of the typing mechanism.  It says that the `__init__` method returns `None`, which is true of the `__init__` method itself, even though when invoked by class instance creation the new class instance is returned.  You can read about the typing system [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).  Type information is not enforced by the Python runtime environment, so you can think of them as specialized comments with a defined syntax.

Comment: @chepner and "Tom Karzes ,  thank you very much, by yours both response, I get it. I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-> None` part is a type hint. It was introduced in PEP 484. You can read more about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-definition-syntax). Both of the `__init__` methods you showed are equivalent in the runtime. Type hints can be used by type checkers, such as [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright).

This piece of `mypy` documentation sums it up perfectly:

> As mypy is a static analyzer, or a lint-like tool, the type annotations are just hints for mypy and don’t interfere when running your program. You run your program with a standard Python interpreter, and the annotations are treated effectively as comments.

This is also an interesting piece of the PEP 484 that explains the rationale behind putting `-> None` in the `__init__` method.

> (Note that the return type of **init** ought to be annotated with -> None. The reason for this is subtle. If **init** assumed a return annotation of -> None, would that mean that an argument-less, un-annotated **init** method should still be type-checked? Rather than leaving this ambiguous or introducing an exception to the exception, we simply say that **init** ought to have a return annotation; the default behavior is thus the same as for other methods.)